# One liner for padding columns (similar to printf) of output from the previous pipe command?

Tags: bash, command-line, printf

I'd normally use `printf` to pad each cell with enough whitespace to maintain header position over its respective column.

Ultimately I can  just iterate over each line of the output and do enough `cut` invocations so that I `printf` each line, but that seems like a horribly inefficient way of going about it.

Is there a way I can turn the above output into a pretty printed format without going multiple lines or multiple calls to the same utilities?

Comment: input | sed -r 's/^(([^,]*.){$FIELD_COUNT}).*/' | ( IFS=, ; set -f -- $(cat) ; printf args "$@" )

Comment: You could also do the above without `sed` at all - ( IFS=, ; set -f -- $(input) ; while [ $# -ge {$FIELD_COUNT} ] ; do { printf args $1… {$FIELD_COUNT} ; shift {$FIELD_COUNT} ; done )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone posted the answer then immediately deleted it for some reason. They pointed me to the `column` command (which I just wasn't aware existed until now). Their original command wasn't 100% correct but it was still the correct response:

```
root@xxxxxxlp01 ~ $ spacewalk-report entitlements | cut -d, -f4,5-6 | column -t -s,
entitlement                                                                  used  total
RHN Management Entitled Servers                                              114   391
RHN Provisioning Entitled Servers                                            114   390
Virtualization Host Entitled Servers                                         0     13
Clustering technology beta                                                   0     1
Private Channel Family 1                                                     22
RHEL AS (v. 4 for x86) SDK                                                   0     12
RHEL Clustering                                                              0     1
RHEL Clustering Option Beta Debuginfo (v. 5)                                 0     1
RHEL Clustering Option Debuginfo (v. 5)                                      0     1
RHEL Desktop Beta Debuginfo (v. 5)                                           0     80
RHEL Desktop Debuginfo (v. 5)                                                0     80
RHEL Desktop FasTrack                                                        0     80
RHEL Desktop FasTrack (v. 5)                                                 0     80
RHEL Desktop Multi OS                                                        34    80
RHEL Desktop Supplementary                                                   18    80
RHEL Desktop Supplementary Beta Debuginfo (v. 5)                             0     80
RHEL Desktop Supplementary Debuginfo (v. 5)                                  0     80
RHEL Desktop Virtualization Beta Debuginfo (v. 5)                            0     80
RHEL Desktop Virtualization Debuginfo (v. 5)                                 0     80
RHEL Desktop Workstation                                                     16    80
RHEL Desktop Workstation Beta Debuginfo (v. 5)                               0     80
RHEL Desktop Workstation Debuginfo (v. 5)                                    0     80
RHEL Desktop Workstation FasTrack                                            0     80
RHEL Desktop Workstation FasTrack Debuginfo (v. 5)                           0     80
RHEL FasTrack                                                                0     59
RHEL FasTrack Debuginfo (v. 5)                                               0     59
```

The only difference between this answer and the one they deleted was this one keeps the `cut` command and adds a `-s,` to the end. If he posts again, I'll accept it as the answer just to be fair.